# Удаление записей

Tags: mysql, sql-server, запрос

Есть таблица с комментами юзеров к товарам.

```
id,userid,itemid,text,date
```

Нужно почистить таблицу так, чтобы на товар осталось не больше 20 комментов последних по дате. БД mssql, запрос можно и на mysql - переделаю. Не имею представления, как это сделать даже вложенными запросами...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from t
from (select *, Row_number() over (partition by itemID order by date desc) as rn
from [Table]) as t
where rn > 20
```